# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/jfree/chart/plot/PlotOrientation

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, netbeans-8

I'm trying to show a graphic report in a web application run in a local machine using **wildfly-8** but a I had next error.

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/jfree/chart/plot/PlotOrientation;
>   at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
>   at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2575)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_31] at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:2060)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_31] at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getDeclaredSUID(ObjectStreamClass.java:1659)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_31] at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.access$700(ObjectStreamClass.java:72)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_31] at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:480)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_31] at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:468)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_31] at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_31] at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.(ObjectStreamClass.java:468)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_31] at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:365)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_31] at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:602)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_31] at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1623)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_31] at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_31] at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1623)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_31] at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_31] at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_31] at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_31] at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_31] at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:501)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_31] at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseChart.readObject(JRBaseChart.java:828)
>   [jasperreports-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]

I imported libraries like:

1. commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
2. commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
3. commons-digester-1.7.jar
4. commons-javaflow-20060411.jar
5. commons-logging-1.1.jar
6. groovy-all-1.5.5.jar
7. iText-2.1.0.jar
8. jasperreports-3.7.0.jar
9. JFreechart 1.0.19 (most recent)

But I'm still having that error. Anybody can help me ?

I have this in a server with jboss 6.1.0 functional but in local machine doesn't works.

Comment: i already use but is the same error, i just implement it on japersoft library folder and also in my project from netbeans.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the files tab, expand the .war file in the dist subdirectory, expand the WEB-INF.lib directory within the .war file and check to see if the jfreechart is in there. If it is expand its org.jfree.chart.plot directory to check for PlotOrientation.class.

[image]

...

[image]

...

[image]

If its there, maybe your wildfly is out of sync. Undeploy your web application, stop wildfly, and restart.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a dependency manager (Maven, SBT, Ivy, Gradle, etc.) copy and paste the respective snippet above into your project file. If you're using a dependency manager, that's all there is to resolving this exception.

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/info/novatec/testit/livingdoc-confluence5-plugin/1.1.2/livingdoc-confluence5-plugin-1.1.2.jar